Destructively reading messages from IBM MQ Queue are not being removed from queue
I'm trying to implement a destructive reading from WebSphere, sort of like purging the queue.
The code works fine at times but there are times where the purge is very inconsistent. Sometimes it will purge all of the messages on the queue and sometimes there maybe 1 or 2 messages left on the queue. I even log out the queue depth and it shows that there are 0 messages left on the queue.
However, when I manually look at the queue, I see there are still messages left on the queue. This only happens sometimes so it's hard to pin point where the problem is.
Here's my code:
  void purge() {
      MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(queueManager)
      int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED + CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE + CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
      MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
      gmo.options = CMQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + MQC.MQGMO_ACCEPT_TRUNCATED_MSG;

      MQQueue queue = qMgr.accessQueue(queueName, openOptions);

      while (true) {
          try {
              MQMessage recceiveMsg = new MQMessage();

              // get the message destructively, no need to perform any operations on it
              queue.get(receiveMsg, gmo);

          } catch (MQException e) {
              if ((e.completionCode == CMQC.MQCC_WARNING) && (e.reasonCode == CMQC.MQRC_TRUNCATED_MSG_ACCEPTED)) {
                  LOG.info("Message has been detected and destructively removed");
              } else {
                  LOG.info("No more messages left on the queue");
                  break;
              }
          }

          LOG.info(queue.getCurrentDepth() + " messages left on the queue");
      }
      queue.close();
      qMgr.disconnect();
  }


Are you sure they are not new messages or were uncommitted by another process?

@JoshMc Great point, I double checked and they are not new messages.

And what about the other half of @JoshMc question? Could they have been uncommitted at the time you were purging the queue? DISPLAY QSTATUS has an attribute UNCOM which would show you whether there were any before you start.

Remember that if the CURDEPTH is 0 but there are uncommitted messages, this tells you that there is an uncommitted MQGET of a message. Is there any other application processing this queue when you are trying to purge it?

@MoragHughson There should have only been one application processing this queue. But you may be right about the uncommitted messages.

@Computable Apologies, typo in my code. It's actually outside of the loop.
